# Why Action Plan is not working on Work Order?

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger

i have need to create **Action Plan** on **Work Order** object also need to used work order on related object of Action Plan, but the Action Plan object was managed package so that cant be changes in code. Work order was standard object Cant access anything to change in settings. i have refer https://github.com/SalesforceLabs/ActionPlansV4/blob/main/README.md but its only provides for custom object. Please advise for creation action plan for standard Work Order object.
In Below Screenshot can't be shown work order existing records.
[image]

Comment: Sorry to say, but it's not easy to understand your question. Take "In Below Screenshot can't be shown work order existing records". Do you miss the possibility to select any existing work order records in this page? Without any familiarity with your object hierarchy, I'd check [OWD](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_sharing.htm&type=5) and permissions of your user profile.

Comment: hey @FelixvanHove basically i need to create  action plan on work order but the problem is that i can't found any record related to work order. this filed is not working so i need to some advise for access existing record. is their any way ? as per your advise OWD already set on public read/write. i have an issue because its an managed package so please suggest me any better way to fix this issue .